# c++ to c# dll import ReadImage

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have this function in C++ and i want import it in c#

```
BS_RET_CODE BS_ReadImage( int handle, int imageType, unsigned char* bitmapImage, int* imageLen)
```

I've tried

```
[DllImport("BS_SDK.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "BS_ReadImage")]
public static extern int BS_ReadImage(int handle, int imageType, IntPtr bitmapImage, ref int imageLen);

IntPtr image = new IntPtr();
int len = 0;
BSSDK.BS_ReadImage(m_Handle, 0xff, image, ref len);

byte[] _imageTemp = new byte[len];
Marshal.Copy(image, _imageTemp, 0, len);
```

but i get an Access Violation Exception

Comment: It has to read the image into something.  That is surely the buffer you are supposed to pass as the *bitmapImage* property.  Make it a byte[] instead.

Comment: I Solved it

    [DllImport("BS_SDK.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "BS_ReadImage")]
    public static extern int BS_ReadImage(int handle, int imageType, byte[] bitmapImage, ref int imageLen);


    byte[] image = new byte[84022];
    int len = 0;
            
    BSSDK.BS_ReadImage(m_Handle, 255, image, ref len);
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(image)));
    b.Save(@"C:\temp\image.jpg");

Comment: but i don't know how i'm supposed to use imageLen to reserve memory if i don't know it until i call BS_ReadImage, i set image byte[] with big size and then i looked into imageLen to set the byte[] with the proper size

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check that `len` is infact equal to or greater than the size of `image`??

Where is the exception occurring? What line exactly?